# Predefined order of executing threads

Tags: multithreading, data-structures, concurrency, synchronization, locking

There are 10 functions, say, `Function_1` (that prints 1 and exits), `Function_2` (that prints 2 and exits), and so on till `Function_10` (that prints 10 and exits).

A main function forks 10 threads, T1 to T10. T1 calls `Function_1`, T2 calls `Function_2`, and so on till T10 calls `Function_10`.

When I execute the main function, I expect output as 1 2 3 4 ... 10.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The _best_ way to achieve that is to call the functions from a single thread in the order you want them called. The _entire point_ of threads is to allow functions to run _[concurrently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science))_  and concurrency only makes sense when the order does not matter.  @mevets answer (below) is a good explanation of how to accomplish what you, presumably, were _assigned_ to accomplish; but just be aware that the exercise is completely unrealistic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to establish what amounts to a protocol between T0 (main) and each of T{1..10}.   That protocol could look like (T0 sends Print to Tn; Tn sends Printed to T0).
If you don't have message passing (which would make life easy; look at golang if interested), you can simulate it crudely with condition variables.   Make a structure that looks like:

```
struct ToDo {
     enum { Print, Printed} Op;
     int Id;
     condvar_t cv;
     mutex_t   lock;
};
```

And each thread then becomes:

```
void *Proc(int Id, struct ToDo *Next) {
      lock(&Next->lock);
      while (Next->Id != Id) {
           condvar_wait(&Next->cv, &Next->lock);
      }
      assert(Next->Op == Print);
      printf("%d\n", Id);
      Next->Op = Printed;
      Next->Id = 0;
      condvar_signal(&Next->cv);
      unlock(&Next->lock);
      ....
}
```

And finally your program

main() {
      struct ToDo Next;
      ... /* create condvar, lock */
      lock(&Next.lock);
      Next.Id = 0;
      /* Create threads and pass structure */
      int i;

```
  for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
       Next.Id = i;
       Next.Op = Print;
       condvar_signal(&Next.condvar);
       while (Next.Id != 0) {
            condvar_wait(&Next.condvar, &Next.lock);
       }
       assert(Next.Op == Printed);
  }

  ... /* join threads */
  exit(0);
```

}